# MediaStore - querying just for images return no results

Tags: xamarin.android, mediastore

I'm making a custom gallery screen for my app and I want to only list images & videos, but when I setup my query, nothing is coming back, I have the proper permissions and I ask for them before the query even runs.

here is a simplified version of what I have:

```cs
var galleryItems = new List<string>();
var uri = MediaStore.Files.GetContentUri("external");
var projection = new[]
{
    MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id,
    MediaStore.Files.IFileColumns.MediaType,
    MediaStore.Video.IVideoColumns.Duration
};

var selection = $"{MediaStore.Files.IFileColumns.MediaType} = ? OR {MediaStore.Files.IFileColumns.MediaType} = ?";
var selectionArgs = new [] { MediaType.Image.ToString(), MediaType.Video.ToString() } };
var mediaCursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, $"{MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateTaken} DESC");
var columnIndexId = mediaCursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id);
var columnIndexMediaType = mediaCursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.IFileColumns.MediaType);
var columnIndexDuration = mediaCursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.IVideoColumns.Duration);

while (mediaCursor.MoveToNext())
{
    var mediaType = (MediaType)Enum.Parse(typeof(MediaType), mediaCursor.GetString(columnIndexMediaType));

    if (mediaType == MediaType.Image)
    {
        galleryItems.Add($"{MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri}/{mediaCursor.GetString(columnIndexId)}");
    }
    else
    {
        galleryItems.Add($"{MediaStore.Video.Media.ExternalContentUri}/{mediaCursor.GetString(columnIndexId)}");
    }
}
```

from what I saw in the android docs this should work, not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I had to convert the enum to an int

so this line:

```cs
var selectionArgs = new [] { MediaType.Image.ToString(), MediaType.Video.ToString() } };
```

should have been:

```cs
var selectionArgs = new [] { $"{(int)MediaType.Image}", $"{(int)MediaType.Video}" } };
```

now it works, hopefully if someone (or future me, HI!) stumbles upon on this, it'll help them.